# how to make the fire cast light according to the way the fire move?

Tags: particles

how do I make the fire cast light according to the way the fire move (in cycles)? for example if the fire jumps the whole room should be brighter, and if the fire is inside fireplace, the part that is exposed to the fire should be brighter from the rest of the room for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP6cG27blwE
There is no difference in the light next to the fireplace

[image]

[image]

fire node setup

Comment: Check Andrew Price tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI

Comment: It is based on It

Comment: Could you please add fire node setup?